# EGit Clone Does not work

Tags: egit

I can clone from command line but not via EGit (Eclipse). Extensive Googling did not yield an answer. This has been asked many times before, and I tried pretty much everything suggested. 
I keep getting" cannot open git-upload-pack". Yes, I can clone from command line and then import. Then commit via Eclipse and push from command line. I have been doing so for a while now. Everything except pull and push works. Is this functionality just broken?

Comment: Which version of EGit do you use? What url protocol do you use and which kind of authentication?

Comment: HTTPS, Egit 1.3.0.201202151440-r

Comment: I am having this problem. http://code.google.com/p/gitblit/issues/detail?id=4

Answer (score 2):

- if you are sitting behind a proxy check your Eclipse proxy settings
- any errors in the Eclipse error log ?
- EGit 1.3.0 can definitively clone over https
- what kind of http authentication does your git server want ? JGit/EGit at the
  moment only supports basic and digest authentication
- is your server using a self-signed SSL certificate ? Then you either need to
  tell Java (on the EGit end) that it should trust this certificate or switch
  off the SSL certificate using the git configuration parameter https.verify=false

Answer (score 1):

The following describes the issue. There is no solution.
http://code.google.com/p/gitblit/issues/detail?id=4

Answer (score 1):

Another issue we came across: if you have an instance of Fiddler running, then it will (in effect) put a proxy between you and the outside world.

Kill Fiddler or limit what HTTPS trafic is decrypted by Fiddler for GIT to work correctly.

[image: limit-fiddler-to-browsers-only]

Answer (score 1):

EGit/JGit 3.0.0 now properly ignores hostname verification failures if http.sslVerify=false.  This matches the behavior of native git.

The previous workaround was to generate a new self-signed, SSL certificate for the ip address/hostname you wished to serve on.