# Eclipse Git self signed certificate error

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

I am trying to clone repository accessible via HTTPS protocol using GIT plugin in Eclipse (Eclipse Juno). This repository has a self-signed certificate.

When I use command line `git clone` and specify the `sslVerify` option, I **am able to clone that repository locally:**

```
git config --global http.sslVerify no
```

However, I wanted to achieve that on EGit or GIT client plugin for Eclipse.

How to set this configuration in Eclipse?

UPDATE:

Have tried this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9742520/405117
Did not work :(

UPDATE 2:

**Error received**:
username@servername/git/repository project: cannot open git-upload-pack:

Please check:

- Network Connection Settings
- Network Connection ->SSH2 Eclipse Preferences

You may also need to restart Eclipse after making these changes.

These changes are already made but no luck :(

UPDATE 3:
Same issues with Egit 2.2.0

Comment: Does eGIT give you any feedback at all?

Comment: @Vikram is there something missing from my answer?

Comment: really sorry I did not look at this earlier...I will respond soon..thanks for your comments!!

Comment: @Manuel I've edited my question to show the feedback from Eclipse..it wasnt very useful though :(

Answer (score 1):

Which version of EGit/JGit are you running?

I found [this](http://code.google.com/p/gitblit/issues/detail?id=4) post which says it is a bug that is being worked on. The post however is from June 2011 so I would've imagined that by now the patch would be there.

It says this on the GitBlit docs. I don't know if you're remote repo is running on GitBlit but it's worth checking the setup section under `Creating your own Self-Signed Certificate` ([link](http://gitblit.googlecode.com/git-history/d9be12d95657435b0542861a64bb1fd781f14de8/setup.html))

> Remote Eclipse/EGit/JGit clients (<= 1.1.0) will fail to communicate
>   using this certificate because JGit always verifies the hostname of
>   the certificate, regardless of the http.sslVerify=false client-side
>   setting.

There's also [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10453881/egit-clone-does-not-work) on SO on the same issue.

As per James Moger's comment apparently the quote from GitBlit should be

> Remote Eclipse/EGit/JGit clients **(<= 2.1.0)** will fail to communicate
>   using this certificate because JGit always verifies the hostname of
>   the certificate, regardless of the http.sslVerify=false client-side
>   setting.

Comment: The JGit situation is currently still the same:  JGit <= 2.1.0 enforces hostname verification even with http.sslVerify=false.  Native Git disables hostname verification which makes this an annoying difference for self-signed certs.

Comment: @JamesMoger Oh, well there we go then. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: I had this same problem, regenerated the server cert for gitblit to match the host name, and it now works in Eclipse.

Comment: This problem should be resolved with JGit 3.0 which will ship with Eclipse Kepler this June 2013.